# VBA Error 91 - Object or With block Variable not set

Tags: vba, macros, coreldraw

Kindly do not mark duplicate as I have properly checked for other related solutions specific to Error 91 but none of those seem to fetch me the solution for the problem I am facing .

Am trying to convert my coreldraw files nested in various folders (about 500 files ) using the following VBA code but its either crashing the application or showing the Error 91 'Object or With Block Variable not set'. The same code absolutely works fine when used with the other Demo Set of files which i created to test.

One case I could presume is the file showing some dialog when processing the script. If yes how should I prevent those dialog boxes. Application.DisplayAlerts = False not working in coreldraw.

But however that case is only an assumption. Can someone help me find the problem. Heres the code

```
Sub NewFolder()
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String
HostFolder = "My folder Path"
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(folder)
Dim SubFolder
For Each SubFolder In folder.SubFolders
    DoFolder SubFolder
Next
Dim File
For Each File In folder.Files
If InStr(File.Name, ".cdr") Then
Application.OpenDocument (File)
End If
Dim filepath As String
filepath = ActiveDocument.FullFileName
Dim doc1 As Document
Dim SaveOptions As StructSaveAsOptions
Set SaveOptions = CreateStructSaveAsOptions
Set doc1 = ActiveDocument

With SaveOptions
    .EmbedVBAProject = True
    .Filter = cdrCDR
    .IncludeCMXData = False
    .Range = cdrAllPages
    .EmbedICCProfile = True
    .Version = cdrVersion17
End With

doc1.SaveAs filepath, SaveOptions
doc1.Close
    ' Operate on each file
 Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: It usually helps when debugging error messages to know what line is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you must check if a valid corel draw file has been found

I don't know CorelDraw VBA but I'd assume you could get the following code as a good start:

```
Sub DoFolder(folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim file
    Dim doc1 As Document
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim SaveOptions As StructSaveAsOptions
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If InStr(file.Name, ".cdr") Then
            Set doc1 = GetDocument(file) '<--| try and get a valid CorelDraw document with the given file: see 'GetDocument()' function at the bottom
            If Not doc1 Is Nothing Then '<--| if you succeed then go on with your code
                filepath = ActiveDocument.FullFileName
                Set SaveOptions = CreateStructSaveAsOptions
                With SaveOptions
                    .EmbedVBAProject = True
                    .Filter = cdrCDR
                    .IncludeCMXData = False
                    .Range = cdrAllPages
                    .EmbedICCProfile = True
                    .Version = cdrVersion17
                End With
                doc1.SaveAs filepath, SaveOptions
                doc1.Close
            End If
        End If
        ' Operate on each file
    Next
End Sub

Function GetDocument(file As Variant) As Document
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetDocument = OpenDocument(file)
End Function
```

as a side note I collected all `Dim` statements outside loops not to have them run multiple time uselessly

Comment: @ManishJain, did you try this?